Why is the GPU not working with Docker 2.4.5-gpu?
I deploy milvus-standalone with gpu,
this is my yaml file.
deploy:
resources:
reservations:
devices:

driver: nvidia

capabilities: ["gpu"]
device_ids: ["0"]
I find gpu cpu is 0%, How do I make sure I'm deployed correctly?

please make sure your NVIDIA drivers and CUDA toolkit are properly installed on your host machine.
This is command to check GPU status:
nvidia-smi

This will show you the GPU utilization & other details. If the command is not found or shows an error, you need to install or fix your GPU drivers and CUDA toolkit.
You should have to install NVIDIA Container Toolkit, Here's you can install it:
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker

Update your docker compose File and please ensure Docker Compose file or deployment YAML file is correctly configured to use the GPU.
example:
version: '3.7'
services:
  milvus-standalone:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:latest-gpu
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]

run the Docker Container with gpu
docker run --gpus all milvusdb/milvus:latest-gpu

Check gpu usage in the container inside your container, for this you can use nvidia-smi. or you need to install nvidia-smi inside the container only if it's not already available.
Also please verify milvus configuration, check the container logs for any errors:
docker logs <containerID>

